# Windows 10 Desktop Wi-Fi via USB adapter keeps disconnecting and cannot reliably ping Google DNS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, ping

This is a Windows 10 Desktop I've used for two years. About 6 months ago, the USB Wi-Fi adapter started  disconnecting after logging in, requiring a manual disconnect and reconnect before it would start working again. This would only happen once, at each login, which I just got used to dealing with and moved on.

Since Monday, I can no longer connect to the internet via the USB adapter for more than a few seconds (and even that is laggy). The router is fine for all other connected devices.

```
Pinging 192.168.15.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.15.154: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.15.154: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.15.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss),
```

Diagnose connection flips between advising the default gateway isn't available, which I just tried pinging and got an error I've never ever had before:

```
Pinging 192.168.15.1 with 32 bytes of data:
No resources.
No resources.
No resources.
No resources.

Ping statistics for 192.168.15.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

Or resetting all network adapters, which I've tried and that didn't work.

When it does connect to the internet for a few seconds, it's wholly unreliable. E.g. pinging google DNS...

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=116
```

This is my routing table:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...24 05 0f 25 b9 da ......Realtek RTL8192CU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
 41...24 05 0f 25 b9 da ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #6
 52...24 05 0f 25 b9 da ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #7
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.15.1   192.168.15.154      4
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.15.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.15.154    258
   192.168.15.154  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.15.154    258
   192.168.15.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.15.154    258
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.15.154    258
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.15.154    258
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 14    296 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    296 fe80::38ad:496e:e834:85ba/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    296 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be hugely appreciated, it's gone from annoying to utterly unusable.

Another thread suggested disabling the WAN Miniport IP device from `devmgmt.msc`. That doesn't work, and I still see 'no resources' when pinging the router.

Switching to the motherboard's built-in wireless adapter, it connects to the internet but it's very very slow (hence using the USB adapter for 2 years). That shows a similar loss of packets when pinging the default gateway...

```
Pinging 192.168.15.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.15.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.15.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 1, Lost = 3 (75% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 2ms
```